# Should all class methods use all dependencies?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

This is really a best practice question regarding dependency injection and use of dependencies in methods.

Take the class below.

```
class Inviter {
  protected $repo;
  protected $emailer;

  public function __construct(\ExampleRepository $repo, \Emailer $emailer) {
    $this->repo = $repo;
    $this->emailer = $emailer;
  }

  public function getInvitedMembers() {
    return $this->repo->getInvitedMembers();
  }

  public function sendInvitation() {
    $this->repo->recordInvitation();
    $this->emailer->sendInvitation();
  }
}
```

When the `Inviter` class is instantiated, an instance of `ExampleRepository` and `Emailer` are injected and their references stored. However, the `getInvitedMembers` method only uses `ExampleRepository` and not `Emailer`.

Is this fine or should these methods be refactored into another class to prevent the overhead of creating and injecting dependencies which may not be used?

If you would like some context, I am programming in PHP and responding to HTTP requests. The application will be run for every request and only one of these methods will be invoked on each run.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, and may get closed FYI. No there is no real problem injecting dependencies that don't get used. However if you have a ton of dependencies that might be a clue you should refactor your class and split it up. There's no way to give you a more specific answer without seeing code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll add some example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that your class does not follow the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), which alone is a reason for refactoring.

Avoiding unnecessary instantiation of objects is desirable, especially if instantiating those dependencies is expensive (maybe a new database connection needs to be created for `ExampleRepository` that otherwise would not be needed).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link to the article. This has cleared this up for me.